# python dice roll simulator, issues with quit and roll again

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to programming and trying to make a dice roll simulator in Python. My code is sort of a combination of two other dice programs I saw. I'm having trouble trying to get quit and re-roll working. I'm using Python 2.7.9 Any tips?

```
import random

def rollDice():
    return random.randint(1,6)

closeProgram = 0

print "Welcome to dice simulator."
print " "

while closeProgram != "q":
    numTimes = input("Enter number of dice rolls: ")
    for i in range(numTimes):
        print rollDice()
    print "Press 'q' to quit or 'enter' to roll again."
    closeProgram = input()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `raw_input`:

```
closeProgram = raw_input()
```

`input` in python 2 is basically `eval(raw_input())` which apart from the fact it is not going to work is also a security risk.

You can cast the input to an int instead of using input:

```
while closeProgram != "q":
    numTimes = int(raw_input("Enter number of dice rolls: "))
    for i in range(numTimes):
        print rollDice()
    closeProgram = raw_input("Press 'q' to quit or 'enter' to roll again.")
```

You should also use a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to catch user input that cannot be cast:

```
while closeProgram != "q":
    try:
        numTimes = int(raw_input("Enter number of dice rolls: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Integer values only allowed")
        continue
    for i in range(numTimes):
        print rollDice()
    closeProgram = raw_input("Press 'q' to quit or 'enter' to roll again.")
```

Comment: @logc, yes that is True, just need to cast to int also.